# Proof that taking the complex conjugate of any expression is the same as replacing $i$ with $-i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was always told that taking the complex conjugate of any expression can be done by just replacing the $i$ with $-i$. However I never found a proof of such thing, and as a physicist I always did this, and it always worked.

Today, thinking about this problem, I sketched this simple proof, and I would like to know if it is correct, and also if someone have another simple proof of this property.

My proof is as follows:

Suppose you have a complex function of multiple variables:

\begin{equation}
u=f(z_1,z_2,...) = a + ib \quad \text{where} \quad (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \quad \text{and} \quad z_i \in \mathbb{C}
\end{equation}

We can find another function $ g(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, ..., k)$ where $(a_i,b_i) = (Re(z_i), Im(z_i))$, that satisfies:

\begin{equation}
g(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2..., k) = f(z_1,z_2,...) \quad \text{for} \quad k=i. 
\end{equation}

So now we can see that, since

\begin{equation}
u=f(z_1,z_2,...) = g(a_1, b_1,..., i) = a + ib
\end{equation}
It follows that:
\begin{equation}
u^*=(f(z_1,z_2,...))^* = (g(a_1, b_1, ..., i))^* = a - ib
\end{equation}

However, if $g(a_1, b_1, ..., i) = a + ib \Rightarrow a-ib = g(a_1, b_1, ..., -i) $ since $a,b$ are real.
Which leads us to conclude:

\begin{equation}
(g(a_1, b_1, ..., i))^* = g(a_1, b_1, ..., -i)
\end{equation}

$\blacksquare$

Comment: It's only true if $f$ has a power series with *real* coefficients, and you rather want $f(z_1^*,z_2^*,\dots)=(f(z_1,z_2,\dots))^*$.

Comment: Sorry, I  will edit, I have forgot to replace the arguments.

Comment: @Berci Now, I think we can conclude this from my result, if we do leave one argument in complex format $ (h(a_1, b_1, ..., a_k + i b_k, i))^* = g(a_1, b_1, ..., -i) = h(a_1, b_1, ..., z_k^*,-i)$

Comment: Your argument has issues, it's not clear. Rather, if we assume that $f$ has a power series with real coefficients, then just plug in $\bar z$ and use the property for multiplication ($(z^*)^n=(z^n)^*$) and addition only to conclude. Some condition for $f$ is necessary, since for example $f(z)=z+i$ doesn't satisfy $f(z^*)=f(z)^*$.